# Turbo trainer rear wheel movement

Tags: turbo-trainer

I have a Vision Team 30 rear wheel with a Taxc tyre mounted onto a carbon frame bike.

I have recently noticed that the whole wheel sways from side to side about 1-2mm when I pedal. Is this normal for the wheel to have a bit of movement or should it spin in a completely straight line?

The wheel is centered on the the resistance roller and I have tried tightening the quick release but the wheel still moves.

Comment: When standing beside the bike, can you feel any left/right motion of the rim when push/pulling it at the top?  Sounds like bearings may need a tweak to run smoother.

Comment: I'm not sure that 1-2mm is significant.  Frame flex could account for that much motion.  But check rear wheel bearings for play, and check that the mounting in the trainer is solid.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the wheel moves relative to the trainer roller when you are pedaling, that is expected. The trailer and bike frame will flex a little as you apply force to each pedal, which are of course offset to each side of the bike frame.